# Batch file on network drive CALL fails to call another batch file - scheduled task

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, scheduled-tasks

I have a batch file on a network drive (V:), named one.bat.  Inside, it has a CALL to another batch file on the same network drive (V:) in a different folder.  I have one.bat run by double clicking the file, it works fine.  I setup a scheduled task (Windows 2012 R2) and if I have it set to 'Run only when user is logged in', it works fine, but if I switch to 'Run whether user is logged in or not' and run it, it fails to execute the CALL commands inside the one.bat file.  I echo the %ERRORLEVEL% out to a text file and the error level after the call is a '1'.
Any ideas on why this would fail when switch the setting on the scheduled task?  I have run this script without issue on other computers and Windows 2008, so I'm wondering if this is an environmental issue with the mapped drive or something different with 2012?

one.bat:

```
SET Drive=V:
SET WorkEnv=MYWORK
SET CommonCode_Path=%Drive%\%WorkEnv%\Common-Code

CALL %CommonCode_Path%\ParmSettingsSetup.bat
```

This call fails with a ERRORLEVEL of 1.

Comment: Perhaps it doesn't pay attention to mapped drives when set for 'Run whether user is logged in or not.' You could add a line that sends the output of "net use" to a file to see what drives the environment that the file is running in knows about, or other such helpful "where am I" commands.

Comment: Based on the answer here http://serverfault.com/questions/4623/windows-can-i-map-a-network-drive-for-a-service-account it appears that mapped drives are only restored with interactive sessions.

Comment: Thanks.  That looks like the issue.  I added the net use in the script and it's not showing anything when it's set to 'run whether user is logged in or not'.  Looking at the psexec solution.

Comment: You could `pushd \\UNCpath\to\Common-Code` and then `call ParmSettingsSetup.bat` if your scheduled task runs under a user that has rights to the share without having to authenticate interactively.